# How to crop a selected picture in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to crop a selected picture in excel and am trying to use this code:

```
Sub CropPicture()

    Dim shpCrop As Shape
    Dim sngMemoLeft As Single
    Dim sngMemoTop As Single

    Set shpCrop = Selection

    With shpCrop
        sngMemoLeft = .Left
        sngMemoTop = .Top
        With .PictureFormat
            .CropLeft = 10
            .CropTop = 10
            .CropBottom = 10
            .CropRight = 10
        End With
        .Left = sngMemoLeft
        .Top = sngMemoTop
    End With

End Sub
```

However, this gives me a type mismatch runtime error. The problem is this part of the code: 
    Set shp = Selection

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Set shpCrop = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Selection.Name)
```

If you try `? typename(selection)` in the Immediate pane you'll get "picture", but you can get a shape via its name property.

Comment: Very wrong, because excell does not forbid having 2 shapes with same name. Correct answer is `Set shpCrop = Selection.Shaperange(1)`